# How to fix Unsupported locale settings on rabbitVCS show logs

Tags: git, ubuntu, nautilus, rabbitvcs

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 with GIT, Nautilus and rabbitVCS. When i right click git repos files and then show logs it says 'Unsupported local setting'.

I have already tried adding local setting to the .bashrc in the home folder and restarted nautilus but it didnt work.

this is what i added :

export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8

export LANG=en_US.UTF-8

export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found out in the rabbitVCS forum that one has to change the python code itself.

Do this first

```
cd ~/.config/rabbitvcs

gedit RabbitVCS.log
```

Go all the way down in the gedit and check this line :

> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rabbitvcs/vcs/git/**init**.py", line 793, in log locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, current_locale)

Note down the line number and go to that document by terminal

```
$sudo gedit /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rabbitvcs/vcs/git/__init__.py
```

and go to that line (For me its 793) and edit it to the following:

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "C")
```

Once you have followed these steps, the show logs should be working fine.

Comment: I am also facing a similar issue on ubuntu 14.04 and rabbitvcs version 0.16. But I could not find rabbitvcs/vcs/git/__init__.py this entire directory structure in the dist-packages dir. Can you please help?

Comment: @AkshayKasar Check if you have installed it in some other user, Or check if you have downloaded a tar.gz and extracted rabbitvcs to some folder.

Comment: I found the file in the following location /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rabbitvcs/vcs/git/__init__.py, but after making the suggested change, and clicking on show diff the window opens and disappears.

Comment: Oh, i don't know buddy, i didn't face that issue. I think its due to different versions.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the solution that I tried and it is working for me:

**STEP 1:**
Open the below `RabbitVCS.log` file.

```
$ cat ~/.config/rabbitvcs/RabbitVCS.log
```

Scroll to the very bottom of the log and note the line number(in my case it is 824)

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/rabbitvcs/vcs/git/__init__.py", line 824
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, current_locale)
```

**STEP 2:**
Take the `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/rabbitvcs/vcs/git/__init__.py` file from log and open in gedit.

```
$ sudo gedit /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/rabbitvcs/vcs/git/__init__.py
```

**STEP 3:**
Go to that line (in my case, it is 824) and make the following edits:

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "C")
```